# Need some idea on how to store items from page2.php to the cart table?

Tags: php

That's the code below, It will get the ids variable from the url coming from page1.php,

http://www.stores.com/cart.php?action=add_item&ids=1&qty=1&register=0&id=4

then it will either add, update or remove the item you can see the ids in each of the cases along witht he qty and id variable as well found int he url as below: then the script will develop the function AddItem, UpdateItem and RemoveItem. In each of those functions the scrip will either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE from the database the info acourding to the existance of the id inside the database if I am not wrong. Then there is a big query below that will query the results in tables dkb and cdkb according to the id in the table cart If I am not wrong not clear on that. But the thing is that there is a second page call page2.php that has a slightly differences and it is the idc variable in it instead of ids.

http://www.stores.com/cart.php?action=add_item&idc=1&qty=1&register=0&id=4

I might be wrong on building these two url to signal the script to display the results coming from page1.php in a different way and display the results of page2.php in another way.

```
    <?php 
   function ShowCart()

    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
                  cart.id         cart_id,
                  cart.id         cart_id,
                  cart.cartId     cartId,
                  cart.cookieId   cookie_Id,
                  cart.qty        qt_y,                     
                  cdkb.id         cdkb_id,
                  cdkb.name       name,
                  cdkb.image      image,
                  cdkb.price      price,
                  dkb.id          dkb_id,
                  dkb.name        name1, 
                  dkb.image       image1,
                  dkb.price       price2,
                  dbl.product_id  product_id,
              dbl.price       price3,
              dbl.variety     variety,
              dbl.description description                  
    FROM
        cart


        LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
           ON cart.id = cdkb.id    

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
           ON cart.id = dkb.id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbl
           ON dbl.id = dkb.id 


    WHERE
        cart.cookieId ='" . GetCartId() . "' ' ORDER BY cdkb.name AND dkb.name ASC");

    <div id="cart">
<div id="group">
<div id="quantity">Qty</div>
<div id="cartpic">Pic</div>
<div id="product">Product</div>
<div id="cartprice">Price</div>
<div id="remove">Remove</div>
</div>
<?php

$totalCost=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {  
   // Increment the total cost of all items
   $totalCost += ($row["qt_y"] * $row["price1"]);

 ?>

   <div id="cart1">
   <select name="<?php echo $row["ckb_id"];?>" onChange="UpdateQty(this)">
  <?php  print($row["ckb_id"]);?>
  <?php

   for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++)
     {
      echo "<option ";
       if($row["qt_y"] == $i)
         {
          echo " SELECTED ";
         }
        echo ">" . $i . "</option>";
      }
?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div id="cart2">
  <img src="images/logopic.gif"<?php /*?><?php echo $row["image1"]; ?><?php */?> alt="we" width="60" height="50" />
  </div>
  <div id="cart3"><p><?php echo $row["dishname1"]; ?></p></div>
  <div id="cart4"><p>
  $<?php echo number_format($row["price3"], 2, ".", ","); ?></p></div>

  <div id="cart5">
  <p><?php
  printf('<a href="cart.php?action=remove_item&id=%d&idc=%d&register=%s">Remove</a>',  $_GET['id'], $row['ckb_id'], $_GET['register']);
?></p></div>

<hr size="1" color="red" >

<script language="JavaScript">

function UpdateQty(item)
  {
   itemId = item.name;
   newQty = item.options[item.selectedIndex].text;

   document.location.href = 'cart.php?action=update_item&id='+itemId+'&qty='+newQty;
  }

</script>

  <?php
   }
   ?>

   <font face="verdana" size="2" color="black" style="clear:right;">
   <b>Total: $<?php echo number_format($totalCost, 2, ".", ","); ?></b></font></td>


   <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your question is too vague and lacks enough detail to answer. Code?

Comment: @ghoppe I have added the script above

Answer (score 0):

You are getting quantity and other stuff from url, that is not good practice in my view, url tampering can be done (although you are not putting anything secret in url), XSS attacks are common taking place from both urls and input fields. I would suggest you to use `session` instead. Of course nothing is perfect, but it makes it less vulnerable.